# Absolute position elements within iframe?

Tags: html, css

I want to absolute position an element in iframe relative to the document. I'm using this

```
.myClass
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

but it do not position the element at top left of document, it's positioned at top left of the iframe.
How to apsolute position it to the document? jquery/javascript solutions are acceptable

Comment: You can't position child element of iframe outside the iframe.

Comment: An element within an iFrame cannot be positioned relative to an element in the parent document. iFrames and their parent windows don't share resources such as CSS (and therefore also don't share CSS rules). There is no pure CSS way to accomplish this.

Comment: If you found the solution for this from the below answers, accept and upvote the answers. If you got your own answer, put that down and accept it. This will help other users who are looking answers for similar type of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in an `iframe` you load a different website or webpage.

The scripts, elements and CSS have to be controlled from **within** that page.

Comment: However, the iframe can access parent.

Comment: JavaScript running in the iframe can access the parent frame (subject to cross-origin permissions). As far as CSS is concerned it is completely independent.

Answer (score 2):

```
var iframe = top.frames[name].document;
var css = '' +
           '<style type="text/css">' +
           'body{margin:0;padding:0;postiton:absolute}' +
           '</style>';
iframe.open();
iframe.write(css);
iframe.close();
```

You have to do that in HTML not in the css file. But the inner style of the object in the iframe must be handled in the css of the website/server from where the page loads

Comment: can you explain this a little more please? `var iframe = top.frames[name].document;
`

Comment: you have to access the your iframe in html. So you should access it by name or id. Thats what top.frames[name].document do.